# Nikon Camera SDK non-reentrant

Tags: c++, dll, thread-safety

The Nikon SDK allows for a request/response system from PC to camera through USB through the C programming language. When creating two camera objects in two seperate threads, it is not possible to send two commands simultaneously to two seperate cameras. One camera will get its command, and send back the response, and then the second camera will get its command and send back a response. I think it has to do with the fact the DLL the Nikon SDK accesses uses global variables. The DLL is not open-source, so I cannot change or verify this. I did make two seperate copies of the DLL and each thread acesses a seperate copy. Is it possible to send two commands and get responses back at the same time?

Comment: Does having two separate copies of the DLL work?

Comment: How do you get two threads to use different copies of the DLL if they're both part of the same process? The process loader will fix up the DLL accesses and point them to the same DLL long before execution starts.

Comment: @Mark:  By making a 2nd physical copy of the DLL with a different name

Comment: Thread 1 accesses "DLL_1.dll", Thread 2 access "DLL_2.dll". Are you saying that somehow the process loader knows "DLL_1.dll" and "DLL_2.dll" are exact copies of each other and fixes this to use the same file? Would running them in different processes fix this? I did try running different instances, so wouldn't this put them in different processes?

Comment: What happens when 2 DLLs define the same functions? I'm not sure, but I think the first one wins out and the second one gets ignored.

Comment: The Nikon SDK is quite notorious.  Don't get fancy.

Comment: Yes, their SDK is written very poorly, we randomly lose connection with the camera from time to time for what seems to be no reason, and then to get the connection back we have to restart the camera (physically turn it on and off).

Comment: is there a work around, maybe to make the software think USB 1 is from a different PC than USB 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you made two copies of the DLL, they are both being loaded into the same address space / process,  so any conflicts will still overlap.

The first thing I would try is two separate EXEs, each loading the original DLL, so that they are running in different processes. If this allows the two cameras to be controlled independently and simultaneously, you will just need to build some kind of process isolation system :-)

The only way I know to do this (and it's not easy) is to build a COM wrapper around the Nikon DLLs and use IIS to isolate the two instances into their own processes. A slightly easier approach might be to build your own "server" for each camera, running in an EXE process, and send messages to it (maybe just Windows messages) from a third master process.

Comment: I like the server idea, I will try that.

Comment: Oh, does this solution depend on the cameras being able to be controlled independently from two EXE's? If that is the case, I have tried that, and there is still the same problem.

Comment: Ugh. Bad Nikon. There's no reason for this other than crappy programmers.

Comment: This problem was solved by tossing the Nikon camera and using a Canon camera. Much better API.

Answer (score 2):

A brute force solution would be to run each process in its own virtual machine using VMWare Workstation or a similar virtual PC architecture. Of course, now you've got the problem of communicating between two virtual PCs...

Comment: I was thinking this too, but thought this would bring so much more trouble than its worth.

Comment: You would probably need to write your own tunnel, for one thing.  (I dont remember what VMWare calls it)

Answer (score 1):

Those md3 files are not thread safe and contain static functions.  I got this working on the Nikon SDK by dynamically creating a new copy of the md3 file each time a camera is connected.  I had one main md3 for detecting the cameras and then would create a new md3 each time I connected.

Finally, make sure your class is thread safe and contains no global or static functions.  I recommend encasing the base Nikon code into a class.  If your writing a 3rd party dll that requires static functions use a pointer to the Nikon class, for each static call pass the void* object that is created by your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

First think I would try is spawning 2 instances of your application.  One for each camera.

Comment: Forgot to mention. Yes, I already tried that. Still the same Problem. I also tried spawning one instance of my program for camera #1, and Nikon's commerical Camera Control Pro Software connected camera #2. Still the same problem.

Comment: It's very possible that the DLL is actively preventing you from doing this.  If you cant get 2 instances to work, I suspect this may be the case.

Comment: Possible, but each thread uses a seperate DLL. If it is doing this on purpose, is there a way to "trick it", into not doing it.

Comment: You would need to figure out what mechanism it is using, if it is.  Did you make a second copy of the DLL?  Your running in another *instance* right?  Not just another thread?

Comment: In my program, yes I did make a second copy of the DLL. When running to seperate instances, the commerical software uses its own copy of the DLL, while mine uses its own as well.

Comment: Running out of ideas.  You know, if they went to such effort to prevent you from sending messages concurrently, there might be a reason why...

Comment: If there is, I'm willing to suffer the consequences to find out that reason :-). I honestly don't think they are purposely trying to prevent this. The reason being the SDK is very cryptic and low-level written and I can see them doing something sloppy that would prevent this. I even found some function names misspelled in the code. I had to re-write the SDK as a C++ class.

Comment: Also, in the source that accesses the DLL, they use global variables, so it makes sense they would do the same in the DLL. If they did do this in the DLL, could this be the cause of the problem?

Comment: No, a global wouldn't be causing it.  Each instance of the DLL get's its own copy of the globlas.

Comment: Some common methods are: named mutexes, regsitry entries with magic values, "lock" files ont he hard drive

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish. Does the answer take too long, so that you want to get the answers at the same time? Why not simply just create a wrapper and make sure the question/answer are simply synchronous, so that you can access the SDK from any thread (and in case thread X is waiting for a response and thread Y makes a request, thread Y will wait until thread X is getting the response, and then make a request).

Comment: The problem is I need to send two commands at the same time. The command to get the camera to take a high res image takes about 3 seconds (the thread waits until the camera shutters to allow other commands. Thread #2 is getting live-view video stream data, so it looks bad when that gets interrupted for 3 seconds.

Comment: So, to understand what you're trying to do:

Comment: (1) Are you trying to work from your program, with 2 cameras or (2) are you trying to work from your program with 1 camera and have 2 different threads send commands to it or (3) have 2 cameras, and you want to use the original Nikon software on 1st camera and your software on the 2nd camera?

Comment: yes two Nikon cameras, each camera object is defined in a different thread each pointing to a different camera. I can't send commands simultaneously to both cameras at the same time; instead one camera gets the command does its thing, then the second camera gets the second command and does its thing. I want them to do their thing at the same time.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think there's nothing you can do (except for the VM thing) - seems the guys at Nikon never considered the possibility of having 2 cameras connected to your PC; or, they did test it a bit and were done with it.